# MySQL WorkBench format function does not return proper date format

Tags: mysql, date, formatting

I am using MySQL WorkBench and trying to convert the format of a date from the 'yyyy-mm-dd' format into 'Month, year' but when I run the query it returns the wrong format.

Here is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE Event (
ID Integer NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
EventWebLink VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
CFPText VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE EventConference (
EventID Integer NOT NULL,
City VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
Country VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
EvDate DATE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (EventID),
FOREIGN KEY (EventID) REFERENCES Event(ID)
);

SELECT FORMAT(Evdate, 'DDDD, MMMM, YYYY') FROM eventconference, event WHERE EventID = ID;
```

Here is the data that I have:

```
2019-07-14
2019-07-29
```

This is what I want to get:

```
July, 2019
July, 2019
```

This is what I get:

```
20-190-714
20-190-729
```

I have tried every varchar formatting that I can think of and every time I get the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can use `DATE_FORMAT()`. For example:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2019-07-14', '%M, %Y')
```

Result:

```
July, 2019
```

In SQL Server you can use `FORMAT()`, as in:

```
SELECT FORMAT(getdate(), 'MMMM, yyyy')
```

Result:

```
November, 2021
```

Comment: OMG You saved me! I have been looking at 100 webpages for the last 10-12 hours and I could not find this.